# Frying Pans Smoking

Tags: stove

I am new to this forum and needed some advice if possible.  I have both T fal and Faberware pans that within the last month or so seem like there is smoke (yet can't smell anything) coming from the sides and inside of the pans.  I've used numerous different dish washing soap and have used a soft scrubber to make sure there is no build up, yet it still continues to do the same thing.  I even went and bought a new T fal pan thinking it might be a sensor going out on the stove (it's over 12 years old) but it too started smoking/steaming from the sides and inside of the pan.  I live in an apartment and they just gave me a brand new range yet the same thing is occurring.  HELP!  This is driving me nuts.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe they are getting too hot?

Comment: Maybe whatever you are using to try and clean them is itself leaving a combustible residue?

Answer (score 2):

Never use Teflon pans on high heat, especially empty.

The pyrolysis of Teflon begins at ~400F and produces toxic fumes which are harmful to you and to pets (especially deadly to birds). See: [Polymer Fume Fever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer_fume_fever).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with WitYoBadSelf. Teflon has started getting a really bad rap for that reason.

If you need to do high heat cooking and you want something non-stick, the new ceramic coated pans by companies like Green Pan, can take temps up to 800 degrees F.

Cast iron is a nice alternative, but does require a certain amount of know-how as far as care is concerned.

If you have to cook on high heat (again, this is just an assumption being made), I'd go for something that doesn't have a coating. A heavy, aluminum pan is great and should be fairly inexpensive. If you use the right kind of cooking oil for high temps (grape seed or refined sesame seed), you shouldn't have too much of a problem with sticking.